# Hosted Apps in sharePoint and how do we deploy them

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anybody please explain whats are hosted apps and how do we deploy them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get good response for your question, I would prefer you go through this link which gives idea about posting a good question. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First of all, its not `apps`, now its called as `add-ins`.

> Note The name "apps for SharePoint" is changing to "SharePoint
>   Add-ins". During the transition, the documentation and the UI of some
>   SharePoint products and Visual Studio tools might still use the term
>   "apps for SharePoint". For details, see [New name for apps for Office
>   and SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/new-name-for-apps-for-sharepoint#bk_newname)

**SharePoint Hosted Add-ins**

> SharePoint-hosted add-ins, or apps where all components are hosted on
>   either an on-premises or Office 365 SharePoint farm. SharePoint-hosted
>   add-ins are installed on a SharePoint 2013 website, called the host
>   web. They have their resources hosted on an isolated subsite of a host
>   web, called the app web. It’s important to know the difference between
>   host webs and app webs

[Reference here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/choose-patterns-for-developing-and-hosting-your-sharepoint-add-in)

**Deployment:**

Deployment steps include the following:

- Publish the app
- Find the *.app file in published copy
- Upload the *.app package in App catalog
- Add the add-in by going to site content of any site.

Find deployment steps in detail [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-sharepoint-hosted-add-in-app-to-sharepoint-online-in-office-365/)